When to transplant seedlings from coco peat germination medium to soil
I am using coco peat (fine coconut pith with some coconut husk fibers) as a soilless sterile germination medium for seeds. After a seed has germinated, when should I transplant the seedling into soil? I noticed that most of my seedlings quickly become leggy (more than 3 cm). The top portion of their stems start to become very thin, the stem soon folds into two, the seedling collapses, and wilts. Are the seedlings leggy due to insufficient direct sunlight? Should I transplant seedlings into soil as soon as they germinate, so that they can quickly get the nutrients they need to prevent wilting?
For context, I am germinating Lepidium sativum (cress), Nepeta cataria (catnip), and Chamaemelum nobile (chamomile).
